# Can't get updated file on server after git push

Tags: git

I have a local repo on my laptop and a remote repo on a server.

On laptop:

```
$ git pull ssh://xxxx@xxxxxxx/home/gittest/ master
$ cat a.php 
<?php
echo 'hello';
?>
```

so I changed file on laptop

```
$ vim a.php 
$ cat a.php
<?php
echo 'hello';
echo 'hello2';
?>
```

and commit it

```
$ git add a.php
$ git commit -m 'update'
$ git push ssh://xxxx@xxxxxxxx/home/gittest/ master
```

Now I check the file on server

```
$ cat a.php
<?php
echo 'hello';
?>
```

There's still old version

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   a.php
#
```

How to make files update on server?

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be pulling from and pushing to a working repository.

This won't work the way you want it to, because pushing updates the respository, but not the working copy.

After the push, the version in your server working copy appears modified, because it is different to the HEAD version in the repository that was updated by the push.

You need a bare repository to share from.    You can read about that [here](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) among other places.

Answer (score 4):

#### Why this happens

In Git there's

- [working tree] Working tree is the files in your project folder.
- [index] - A snapshot of working tree to save in next commit
- [repository] - the .git/ folder and everything inside it.

When you run `git push`, you only update the repository on the remote server. If remote is not a *bare repository*, it also has a working tree. But it has to be changed by a separate actiion.

#### How do I check if remote repository really gets updated?

Run `git remote show <remote name>` to see branch status

#### How to solve this?

Are you using git for deployment to a server? If so, you need to either:

- after a push login to REMOTE and there run `git checkout master`  to bring the working tree in accordance with the repo
- setup a server-side post-recieve git hook to do it for you.

If you don't use git for deployment, why need any files on the remote? In such case it's best to use a bare repository.

Comment: I agree. It seems like `git reset --hard` is run on local, while it's not true.

Comment: Yes - that's the sort of potential issue with it.   It's not a "normal" way to use git (IME, YMMV etc)

Comment: please evaluate the new version

Comment: Upvoted - you explained the git structure in more detail than I did.